# Send or print membership invoices

Tags: invoice

I'm helping a nonprofit set up membership invoicing. They want to create invoices for the current members. They do not want to use automatic reminders -- they want to choose who they send the invoices to, and when. Additionally, they'll want to send individual reminders to those members who haven't paid.

We've created a Message Template and included personalization tokens for name, organization, etc... but don't see any way to include the due date, membership name and amount due. We know we can include checksum links to a contribution page, but many of their members are brick-and-mortar companies, and they need to print a page and carry it to their accounting departments...

Isn't there some way to generate a simple invoice? Something like "Dear *Joe*, your membership will end soon. To renew, please remit payment of *$150.00* by *January 31, 2016*."

Thanks in advance, and apologies for noobiness.

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 ways:

- Do Use Scheduled Reminders (Administer - Communication - Scheduled Reminders), If you choose Memberships as Entity you can use Membership tokens in the email being sent. You can limit the recipients per group. So if you want to send it one-time, just search for the people you want to send it to, place them in a group and create a reminder with just that group. Let the reminder be sent and remove the reminder.
- Use PDF invoices (enable via Administer - CiviContribute -> CiviContribute Component Settings). You can then search Contributions and send individual pdf invoices per email to the results of your searches.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts. Your first option might work for us. I don't think the second option would work for invoicing future payments, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Renewal Invoices for Memberships is a new CiviCRM extension designed to solve this problem. Please see https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.renewalinvoices