# Creating Invoices for Membership Renewals that are coming due

Tags: civimember, contributions, invoice

How do we go about creating invoices for future contributions? As far as I can tell the workflow only seems to support sending an invoice for current ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create Invoice for future contribution - still you need to create the contribution for future date (Received date) and set the contribution as Pending

This will allow you to create the Invoice and once you have received the amount then you can set the contribution to completed - I guess this helps

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [Send or print membership invoices](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/send-or-print-membership-invoices/31703)

Renewal Invoices for Memberships is a new CiviCRM extension designed to solve this problem. Please see https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.renewalinvoices